# How do I import react-modal into existing application?

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I've been slowly trying to migrate some pieces of an existing, large php/jquery project to use ReactJS, especially using some reusable components. ReactJS has been working well for me, but today I tried to import a library using npm, which is completely new to me.

After running `npm install react-modal` I see that `node_modules\react-modal` (along with several other folders) were created. So far, so good.

However, I cannot seem to include that component into my project. If I try `import ReactModal from 'react-modal';` at the top of my component's .js file, I get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I get errors thrown if I try to include the `node_modules\react-modal\lib\components\Modal.js` file directly, which I realize is probably the wrong approach but I'm grasping at straws here. I suspect I'm missing something basic, but I just can't seem to figure this one out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: here is how I include React into my project currently:

```
<!-- Load React. -->
{if $env=="prod"}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    {* tabs support *}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-tabs@3/dist/react-tabs.production.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/react-tabs@3/style/react-tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

{else}

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    {* tabs support *}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-tabs@3/dist/react-tabs.development.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/react-tabs@3/style/react-tabs.css" rel="stylesheet">

{/if}

{* Babel support *}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

This is the full component (contents of the matchSelector.js file):

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';

/**
 * Select a match with hooks to return the proper match info to the instantiator
 */
class MatchSelector extends React.Component {
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     * 
     * props expected:
     *      className - (optional) use if you want to style the picker button/icon differently. Note that
     *      if given, all standard classes will be overrided.
     * 
     *      type - (optional) can be "text", "icon", "both". Default is "both".
     * 
     *      text - (optional) if type is "text" or "both", the text to use on the button. Default is "Select Match"
     * 
     */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);       // let Dad know what's up

        this.state = {showDialog:false}

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({showDialog:true});
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({showDialog:false});
    }

    render() {
        const defaultClassName = "ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button compressed";
        let className = (odcmp.empty(this.props.className)?defaultClassName:this.props.className);

        return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <button 
                        className={className}   
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            {this.buttonContent()}
                    </button>
                    <MatchSearchDialog
                        show={this.state.showDialog} />
                </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    buttonContent() {
        var text = (odcmp.empty(this.props.text)?"Select Match":this.props.text);

        if (odcmp.empty(this.props.type) || (this.props.type.toLowerCase()=="both")) {
            return (
                <span><span className="ui-icon ui-icon-search inline"></span>{text}</span>
            );
        } else if (this.props.type.toLowerCase()=="icon") {
            return (
                <span className="ui-icon ui-icon-search inline"></span>
            );
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
}

class MatchSearchDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ReactModal isOpen={false}><div>hi</div></ReactModal>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this, I wanted to add my resolution.

I was trying to run a bare bones REACTJS project without webpack. react-modal depends on webpack (as does, I'm sure, many React components). As I'm trying to stay light and agile, I removed the react-modal module and "rolled my own" modal dialog.

FYI, the clue is the "require not defined" error in the console - indicating a non-browser (node.js) function was hit. It was expecting to compile (webpack) into a separate js file using the node.js terminology.

Answer (score 0):

The doc of [the npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) state that to import your modal, you need to write:

`import Modal from 'react-modal';`

It's not `import ReactModal from 'react-modal';` as you tried (**ReactModal** => **Modal**).

With this eveything works fine for me as you can see on [this repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zsimvf?file=index.js). Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import "./style.css";

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

const App = () => {
  const [modalIsOpen,setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={modalIsOpen}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >
        <div>Wow nice modal !</div>
        <button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
        </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I was using ```http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/``` as the documentation, which indicates you use ```ReactModal```. Nonetheless, I tried it with just ```Modal``` and it still fails with "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I can verify your code runs fine for me on Stackblitz.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your component here you want to use this modal please ? Also your react version and eventually webpack configuration if  you use it. I won't be able to help with webpack config but maybe someone will see something

Comment: Code provided above. I don't use webpack; just trying to bootstrap this up right now. React 16.13.1.